# Removing or changing onClick when in different media query

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, styled-components

trying to figure out how to change the onclick on a div when in mobile view media in react,

Currently i have a modal onClick using a Hook on a div and want to remove it and attach another one that opens a new website like in mobile view just to the div.

using @media screen (max-width: 768px)

I'm using styled components also if that helps

Cheers

Comment: The simplest way is to just check `window.innerHeight` when the click is triggered. But, even that isn't that simple if a mobile device is rotated in landscape or has a high pixel density it needs to be accounted for. There are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser) to detect if something is mobile but it can be unreliable.

Comment: @DCTID I think you meant `window.innerWidth`.

Comment: Wouldn't the best way just to be conditionally render the function if it matches the media query inline?

Comment: whats the best way to conditionally render a function inline, ive got  let query = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)")

so if that is true then run the onclick? whats the syntax for react

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick that you can use to access the breakpoints in javascript. Same can work in your scenario. I had used this approach before but for a javascript project. Below is a link for the same,

https://www.lullabot.com/articles/importing-css-breakpoints-into-javascript

The whole idea is to make use of :before or :after pseudo selectors.